# Smarty foreach var incrementing

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, smarty, flags

Edit: Logical error... no need to assign index. We are in the images loop. So

```
 <img src="{$post[0]}" alt="portfolio slider image">
```

and it works.

I try to display a gallery of images from a post in wordpress.

i have a postArray:

```
Array (
    [title] => Projet 2012 
    [content] => blabla
    [images] => Array (
         [0] => Array (
               [0] => http://local.afric-edu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/P1050250.jpg
               [1] => 150 
               [2] => 112 
               [3] => 
         )
         [1] => Array (
               [0] => http://local.afric-edu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/P1000855.jpg 
               [1] => 150 
               [2] => 111 
               [3] => 
         ) 
    )
)
```

In the template, i try to display it in the foreach loop:

```
 {assign var='flag' value=0}

     {foreach from=$postArray['images'] item=post name=post}
          <li>
               {$flag}
               <img src="{$post[$flag][0]}" alt="portfolio slider image">
          </li>

          {assign var='flag' value=$flag+1}

     {/foreach}
```

But when i load the page, i have this:

```
<li>
      0
      <img src="h" alt="portfolio slider image">
</li>

<li>
      1
      <img src="" alt="portfolio slider image">
</li>
```

I do not understand or is my mistake. Maybe I'm tired, but it does not seem to have made logical mistake, though?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the foreach-loop you have to set a `'key'` and an `'item'` element:

```
{foreach from=$postArray['images'] key=k item=post name=post}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logical error... no need to assign index. We are in the images loop. So

```
 <img src="{$post[0]}" alt="portfolio slider image">
```

and it works :)